How to solve WordPress accordion problem on Iphone?
I have built an accordion FAQ on my WordPress website. It works fine on Desktop, Tablet and Android but on iPhones It does not work properly. To make accordions open and close, weirdly I have to use to fingers. I have tried solutions like manipulating cache plugin and creating accordion with 2 different plugins and even theme widget.
Source page link
The video I have recorded of problem
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

What did you use to build the accordion? A plugin, you own code?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For working with accordions in iphone we need to add href="#id" attributes to  tag.
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" href="#collapse1">
    <i class="pull-right icon-chevron-right mobile-nav-icon"></i>
</a>

Please check this link for more help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19869181/4227367
